# How do I get back the dig-down method/block toolbar in pycharm?

Tags: ide, pycharm

I used to run Pycharm CE 2017.1 and loved the dig down into method/block toolbar shown just above the files toolbar.

[image: just to be clear, I men this one]

In the 2017.3 which I downloaded last month I can't figure out how to reinstate the feature. Is it gone for good?

[image: sad developer unable to dig down]

Alt+Q does a similar job but it's not 'persistent'.
Any idea on how to turn it on again? Cheers,

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to breadcrumbs and and they can be enabled @ 'Settings > Editor > General > Breadcrumbs'.